# Mysql - query is slow when IO on linux server wait is high

Tags: mysql

Slow query when IO wait is high.

> **Show from iotop command**
>
> -- TID -- PRIO -- USER -- DISK READ -- DISK WRITE -- SWAPIN -- IO> -- COMMAND
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.25% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.25% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.24% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> **High IO wait start when 6:13:28 PM - 6:13:29 PM (sar command)**
>
> --------------------- CPU -- %usr -- %nice -- %sys -- %iowait -- %steal
>
> -- 6:13:28 PM --- all ----- 2.53 --- 0.00 ---- 2.02 ----- **39.39** ------ 0.00
>
> -- 6:13:29 PM --- all ----- 1.99 --- 0.00 ---- 1.00 ----- **49.25** ------ 0.00
>
> **Got slow query between that time**
>
> Time: 130329 18:13:29
>
> User@Host: wdwdwd[wdwdwd] @ localhost []
>
> Query_time: 2.007902  Lock_time: 0.000025 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1 SET timestamp=1364555609;
>
> UPDATE log_product SET credit=credit+1 WHERE id_product='349721228' and id_user='2021841' LIMIT 1;
>
> **## Question are How to fix this process. What the real cause ? ##**

Comment: I'm getting something similar - high iowait, very low CPU and slow responses. I suspect something funky with InnoDB. Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on the "Log_Product" table by (id_user, id_product) as a single index, not TWO indexes, one by each column.  Also, if the fields are numeric, you don't need quotes...

Comment: i have index both id_user and id_product and each have one index